# Почему я не могу записать полученое изображение через ImageIO.write()?

Tags: java

```
    public static void start(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/username/Downloads/img/image.bmp"));

    frame.add(new JComponent() {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
            affineTransform.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            affineTransform.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
            affineTransform.scale(1.0, 1.0);
            affineTransform.translate(-image.getWidth()/2, -image.getHeight()/2);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(image, affineTransform, null);

            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("/home/username/WorkingSpace/image.bmp"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```